What are the implication with 2-way binding using signals versus using plain properties in Angular?
According to the documentation, I can create a 2-way binding using plain properties but also using signals.
It doesn't explain the pros nor cons implied by either choice.
I can conclude myself that if I want the parent component to act according to a signal (regardless of the binding to its child) I should use signal (and vice versa). But I wonder if that's all there's to it. I suspect that there are deeper implications that may be a future butt-biter.
What are the implied caveats of applying/rejecting signals for two-way bindings between components?
@Component({  template: '<app-child [(beep)]="beep" />', ... })
export class Parent { protected beep = signal("signals"); }

@Component({  template: '<app-child [(beep)]="beep" />', ... })
export class Parent { protected beep = "plain props"; }


Signals allow developers to use reactivity.
Signals help reduce the dependency on zone.js (for change detection) and makes the package lighter (With the same functionality) which angular team is moving for Zoneless Angular.
Signals are the most efficient way to update data, as well as react to changes on the source signal.
When a signal value changes, you can link other properties/actions to happen.
Usually to fully leverage signals power, you need to use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. But it will provide a small boost due to caching of computed.
You are free to use the normal way of doing Angular, there is just a better way to try out.

take the example of computed. The computed signal can be used to derive a state variable based on other state variables.
@Component({  
  template: `
    <app-child [(ngModel)]="beep" />
    
  `, 
})
export class Parent { 
  protected beep = signal("signals"); 
  protected computedSignal = computed(() => {
    const beepVal = this.beep();
    return beepVal * 2;
  });
}

Assume the top computed function is a resource intensive calculation. The computed can save you resources because Computed signals are both lazily evaluated and memoized.
Even if your change detection fires multiple times, the computation happens only once until the signals watched have change then it removes the cached value and reevaluates.

Take the example of effect , which is great for reacting to signal changes and performing side effects.
You are not able to set a signal inside an effect but you can use observables which recalcuate when the signal changes.
@Component({  
  template: `
    <app-child [(ngModel)]="beep" />
    
  `, 
})
export class Parent { 
  protected beep = signal("signals"); 
  protected beepDetails$ = of([]);

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
       if(this.beep() > 100) {
          this.popupService.show('beep value cannot be greater than 100);
       }
    });
  }
}

In this below example the change of beep performs the validation that beep cannot be greater than 100 and shows a popup.

This is barely scratching the surface, for the full comprehensive guide, head over to angular.dev

I'm sorry but I simply don't see the answer to my question here. Could you be more brief or maybe point out to the part that states the difference between those two approaches? (NB. I didn't downvote. I never do. But I can see why someone did. It's a bit difficult to see how the original question has been addressed, at least in my eyes.)

@KonradViltersten model is the signal equivalent of ngModel it does the same thing, my question aims to highlight the advantages of signals and how it offers new features compared to the old method of doing things

Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand. Unfortunately, that's perhaps not the right forum to convey that information, as it doesn't target the question. I can see how one may be mislead by only reading the title. However, if you check again, you'll see that I use model(bla) in both cases. The only difference is the parent's structure: signal versus property. Both seem to be equally mentioned in the linked docs and I wonder why there's no inclination towards any of those nor any implications mentioned about them.
